# Robot framework split string and put in to sheet excel

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I want to split `Transaction ID:211444` , i want to get only value = **'211444'** and put it into sheet excel ? 
anyone please help

Comment: I had to do a lot of string operation and for me the best option was create an external python library that you call from your robot framework test, make the operation that you have to do and return back the result to robot framework

Comment: What have you tried, and what part are you struggling with? Are you asking how to split a string? Are you asking how to create an excel worksheet? Or, are you simply asking us to do all the work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OperatingSystem.py and String.py libraries:

```
${string} =    Convert to String    Transaction ID:211444
${id} =    Fetch From Right    ${string}    ID:
append to file    ids.csv    ID:${id}\n   encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: The first line of your answer will throw an error. That is not how you assign a string to a variable. Also, if you're going to use keywords from any library other than the built-in library, you should show that in your example. Many readers will have no idea where `Fetch from right` came from.

Comment: It would be good to create a complete example, that includes the Library imports and declaration of variables.

Comment: The most common keyword for setting a string variable is [Set Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable), though I guess `Convert to string` works, too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you .

may sure you have **xlsxwriter** installed in your python packages .
else do

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

Below is robotfile content  which will pass the alphanumeric string to a library written in python

**sample.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
#test.py is name of python file in which code to write in excel is written

Library  test.py

*** Variables ***
#This is sample alphanumeric value passed to python function

${test}    pankaj:12232
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    value is
*** Keywords ***
value is

#excel_numeric is function written in python to remove strings and write to excel

    excel_numeric     ${test}
    #log to console    ${compare}
```

Python file 
**test.py**

```
import xlsxwriter
def excel_numeric(arg1):
    import re
    #this will only provide numeric value from strings
    arg2=re.findall(r'\d+',arg1)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'D:\dummy.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for item in arg2:
        print item
        #write takes three arguments,row,column and value
        worksheet.write(0,0,item)
    workbook.close()
```

**output :**

```
12232 - Written in excelfile
```

**Note** 
Make sure you put robot and python file in same directory

Comment: There currently are 2 Robot Framework libraries in [PIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=robotframework+excel&submit=search) and at least 6 more options on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=robotframework+excel&type=). Is there a specific reason you prefer to custom develop over the other options?

Comment: Can you please let me know about those libraries or any example, I was not aware of them.

Comment: Follow the links in my comment. These are the words PIP and GitHub.