# How do I strip a section of URL and assign to a variable

Tags: robotframework

I want to assign the current URL to a variable and then get a substring of this and assign to a second variable.  The URL would be in the format of http://qasite.test/lists/123456789#

So I need 123456789# assigned to variable 2

I understand I can firstly get the URL by using:

${href}=    Get Location

Comment: In which language?

Comment: Robot Framework

Answer (score 1):

After working a lot I think following approach may work.(I don't have robot framework environment but following might work.)

[robot framework string manipulations official docs](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html)

1. Use **Fetch from right** for your url (http://qasite.test/lists/123456789#) you will get this (1234567789#)

   ```
    ${string} =    Convert to String    http://qasite.test/lists/123456789#
    ${id} =    Fetch From Right    ${string}    /
   ```

   This link might help [fetch from right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469710/robot-framework-split-string-and-put-in-to-sheet-excel)
2. Now get the length of ${id} using **Get Length** of robot framework
3. Now use **Get Substring** starting index from (0 to length or length-1) You will get **123456789**

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a string. It's already a string.